# Downloading Youtube videos in a text file...?

Tags: batch, shell-script, youtube, pipe

If you are familiar to Linux, see the following script...

I have a text file with a (list.txt) of Youtube URLs separated by new line... and I use

```
cat list.txt | youtube-dl -f best
```

to download all in the list

This works fine but I want to emulate it on a Windows Batch file..

```
set /p data=<list.txt
youtube-dl -f best %data%
```

This works too.. BUT it downloads only the first video on the list.

A Simple solution w.r.t coding would be preferred.

***PS:Also it is certain that I'm not looking for solutions using youtube-dl commands***

Comment: Why don't you just use `youtube-dl -a list.txt`?

Comment: @Attie Okay, you may write it as an answer.

Comment: What did you mean "_not looking for solutions using youtube-dl commands_"?

Answer (score 57):

Rather than piping it in, you could use functionality provided by `youtube-dl` - it has a parameter that allows you to point at a text file containing a list of URLs - one per line.

> `-a`, `--batch-file FILE`
>
> File containing URLs to download (`-` for stdin), one URL per line. Lines starting with `#`, `;` or `]` are considered as comments and ignored.

In your situation you'd use:

```
youtube-dl -f best -a list.txt
```

Comment: This seems to me as being the best answer for it uses the original tool to do the same and there is a Windows version too. So basically all you need to do is reformat your command according to the answer provided by Attie and just put it in a folder with a batch script and relevant list file. Then all you'll have to do is edit your list file and run your script.
Otherwise, though I don't know it properly, I'd suggest looking on PowerShell side. From what I saw it seems they at last included a lot of nice features and commands.

Comment: when I try to use a batch-file I always get ```[youtube] xxxxxx: Downloading webpage
ERROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden``` where xxxxxx is the video in ```https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx```

Comment: @lbutlr It looks like the video is private.

Comment: No, as it works fine when I do not try to use a batch file.

Comment: This discussion isn't really supposed to be conducted in comments... but, 1) Have you updated `youtube-dl`?, 2) Can you share the full link so we can try?

Comment: if someone is getting 'requested format not available' error, try `-f bestvideo+bestaudio` flag

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `youtube-dl -a yourList.txt` where yourList is a file containing URL's delimited by linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube-dl allow downloading multiple URL at once, so here is a simple solution:

```
youtube-dl $(cat my-links.txt | xargs)
```

Comment: The subshell is unnecessary. xargs will append whatever it gets on standard input to the end of the commandline. So just do `cat my-links.txt | xargs youtube-dl -f best`.

Comment: thats event better, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a strictly batch file solution with youtube-dl i suggest you use this

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in (videolinks.txt) do (youtube-dl -f best %i)
```

it goes through the whole file line by line and downloads whatever is on the line (if its a valid link)

if you want to use it in a *.bat file make sure to use double % [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)

> Use a single percent sign (%) to carry out the for command at the command prompt. Use double percent signs (%%) to carry out the for command within a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a file with URLs or explicit YouTube-IDs. Then you can make a script as follows:

```
FILE=YT-List.txt #the file with the urls or youtube-ids: 1 item per line
while read line
do
  F1=$(echo $line)
  youtube-dl  -f22 -c -R infinite "$F1" &
done < $FILE
sleep 7
echo "I AM READY"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).